# Variadic Templates on Method Accepting Function Pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

The following code looks to me as though it should be working fine, but it produces

```
C2738: could not deduce template argument for 'Type'.
```

in VS2013.

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename...Args>
uint GetParameterSize(ReturnType(*method)(Args...))
{
    return ParameterSize<Args...>();
}

template <typename Type, typename...Remaining>
uint ParameterSize()
{
    uint output = sizeof(Type);

    if (sizeof...(Remaining) > 0)
    {
        output += ParameterSize<Remaining...>();
    }

    return output;
}

void MyMethod3(int a, char b, int c )
{
}

// Elsewhere
uint size = GetParameterSize(&MyMethod3);
```

I thought, "Oh maybe it's because it doesn't have a final condition." So I added:

```
template <typename Type>
uint ParameterSize()
{
    return sizeof(Type);
}
```

Which led to

```
C2668: 'ParameterSize' ambiguous call to overloaded function.
```

I mean, it looks simple enough and I think it should work. How can the compiler not deduce the arguments? I'm new to variadic templates so I might be missing something, but some help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any arguments to `ParameterSize()` that would allow it to deduce `Type`.

Comment: The types of the arguments of the function pointer provided will be the parameter pack provided to `ParameterSize`, no?

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do.  You want `Args...` to be `int a, char b, int c`.  I would do a `static_assert()` in `GetParameterSize` to see if `Args...` is actually getting set.  I would guess it might not be.

Comment: It is. `sizeof...(Args)` yields 3 in `GetParameterSize`. To see that, I had to comment out the recursive call to `ParameterSize`.

Comment: When `Remaining` is empty, you "call" (instantiate) in the first version `ParameterSize<>()` which doesn't specify `Type`, and `Type` cannot be deduced, hence the error. In the second version (with the overload), when you call `ParameterSize<some_type>()`, both overloads are viable and neither is more specialized; hence the ambiguity.

Comment: An `if` semantically is always a run-time decision. So `ParameterSize<Remaining...>()` is also instantiated when `sizeof...(Remaining) == 0`, which leads to the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix I can think of is to invoke overload resolution:

```
template <typename Type>
constexpr unsigned ParameterSize(int)
{
    return sizeof(Type);
}

template <typename Type, typename...Remaining>
constexpr unsigned ParameterSize(...)
{
    return sizeof(Type) + ParameterSize<Remaining...>(42);
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename...Args>
constexpr unsigned GetParameterSize(ReturnType(*method)(Args...))
{
    return ParameterSize<Args...>(42);
}

void MyMethod3(int a, char b, int c )
{
}

int main()
{
    // Elsewhere
    unsigned size = GetParameterSize(&MyMethod3);
}
```

The ellipsis makes the second overload a worse match than the first for arguments of type `int` (such as `42`), that's how the ambiguity (`ParameterSize<one_argument>(42)`) is resolved.

Comment: With the `constexpr`, if you're using Visual Studio you'll need at least VS2013; otherwise just remove the `constexpr`.

Comment: You, sir, are good. I'm not a big fan of this, per-say. But it works for what I want without having to restructure things. This was just an example, the actual problem is a bit bigger than this but you've definitely gotten me where I need to be. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (sizeof...(Remaining) > 0)
    {
        output += ParameterSize<Remaining...>();
    }
```

The problem is that the above code is a run time check, not a compile time.  So even though once `Remaining` is length 0, it still has to compile the signature for `ParamaterSize<>()`, even though it'll never be executed.

For this sort of problem, you can actually do everything at compile time.

```
template<typename ... Args>
struct ParameterSize;   
{
   static const uint value = 0;
};

template<typename Type, typename... Remain>
struct ParameterSize<Type, Remain...>
{
   static const uint value = sizeof(Type) + ParameterSize<Remain...>::value;
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename...Args>
uint GetParameterSize(ReturnType(*method)(Args...))
{
    return ParameterSize<Args...>::value;
}
```

Example at http://ideone.com/6aYRzI

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers to why your code isn't working, so instead I'll give you an alternative.  Since you seem to be accumulating `sizeof(Type)` to get the total stack size required to store function parameters, here's how I would do it:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>

    template <class ... Args>
    unsigned ParameterSize()
    {
        unsigned sizes[sizeof...(Args)] = {sizeof(Args)...};
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(sizes), std::end(sizes), 0);
    }

    template <typename ReturnType, typename...Args>
    uint GetParameterSize(ReturnType(*method)(Args...))
    {
        return ParameterSize<Args...>();
    }

    void MyMethod(int,int,int){}

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << GetParameterSize(&MyMethod) << std::endl;
    }
```

Since you already had runtime code in your example, I'm assuming you don't mind some of the work being done at runtime.